# How to link excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I've linked an excel spreadsheet to a power point presentation; however, it is only showing a portion of the cells.  When I double click the linked workbook there is no way to adjust the size.  I've tried paste special with the cells I want highlighted and I've also tried inserting an object.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the double click give the option to resize and the adjustment doesn't take, or does it just not give the option to resize to begin with?

Comment: One user reported that changing their Windows display settings to 125% solved the problem (or seemed to).  Here's the post on MS Answers (go all the way to the end of the thread):  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_windows8/powerpoint-paste-link-from-excel-truncates/cba3f058-f269-4f07-a492-1702b16f840f

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the whole spreadsheet during the presentation? If so, just Alt-Tab and open it in Excel.

Do you need only a small part of the spreadsheet, such as a graph or table of data? If so, copy that graph or data, and Paste-Special as Picture (Enhanced Metafile)

Answer (score 0):

One easiest method, select the range copy and use paste link on slide, will be dynamic range.

Or insert sheet as image but be sure your sheet dimensions should be smaller.